# Net::HTTP failing on a head request

Tags: ruby, http, net-http, http-head

I'm trying to make an HTTP Head request using Net::HTTP.

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://github.com/rails/rails")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = http.head(uri)

puts request
```

fails.

AFAICT, this is because Net::HTTP is waiting on a response body which will never come. How do I ask Net::HTTP to make a request and not wait on the response body?

Comment: The right way to do a HEAD request with curl is the `--head` option. With `-X HEAD`, curl sends the HEAD method, but still waits for a response body—hence the delays.

Comment: @Vasily--Ah, that makes sense. So the issue is probably that internally Net::HTTP is waiting for a response body and not getting one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head) properly, it works just fine. The library implementation probably has some assumptions on the usage when it determines whether to read the payload.

```
response = nil
Net::HTTP.start('github.com', :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  response = http.head('/rails/rails')
end

response.each { |k, v| [k, v] }
```